# add image in treeView

Tags: c#

```
TreeNode desktop = new TreeNode();
desktop.Text = "Desktop";
desktop.Tag = "Desktop";
Mycomputer.ImageIndex = 1;
Mycomputer.SelectedImageIndex = 1;
desktop.Nodes.Add("");
treeView1.Nodes.Add(desktop);

TreeNode Mycomputer = new TreeNode("My Computer");
Mycomputer.ImageIndex = 1;
Mycomputer.SelectedImageIndex = 1;
treeView1.Nodes.Add(Mycomputer);
```

I am using the `ImageIndex` property but where is the image?

How do I choose my image and from where?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For `ImageIndex` to have any meaning, your tree view should have an `ImageList` assigned. The `ImageIndex` property refers to the *index within the image list* of the image you want to present.

You can create an `ImageList` manually, or via the designer. This example demonstrates a method of creating and assigning an `ImageList` manually:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.imagelist.aspx

For me, I just pop open the designer, select the tree view, find the ImageList property in the property editor, and click it to launch a popup window that allows me to select and import a set of resources that become the image list.

Here are some screenshots of the process:

The ImageList component can be dragged onto your form from the toolbox.

[image: Screen01]

It has an Images collection among its properties.

[image: Screen02]

With the image list on the form, you can select it for the ImageList property on your tree view.

[image: Screen03]

I hope that helps fill some of the gaps.

Good luck!

Comment: imageList property showing none, and dont have any browse option .

and manually 
myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("Default.gif"));
is not working.

am i missing any assembly reference??

thank you.

Comment: @ashish: I updated the post with screenshots to help fill the gaps in my explanation.